# Spring Overloaded Constructor Autowiring

Tags: java, spring, constructor

I have a class with overloaded constructors, like this:

```
@Component
public class MyClass {
    private ClassA myMemberA;
    private ClassA myMemberB;

    @Autowire
    public MyClass(@Qualifier ("qualifierA") ClassA objectA, ClassA objectB) {
       myMemberA = objectA;
       myMemberB = objectB;
    }

    @Autowire
    public MyClass(ClassA objectA) {

       myMemberA = objectA;
    }
}
```

Basically, one constructor has two arguments of `ClassA`, and one constructor has just one argument. I have two beans of type `ClassA` defined.
I would like to have one of the two constructors invoked and autowired accordingly depending on the use case.

When I ran this code, I got the error:

```
Invalid autowire-marked constructor: ...
Found another constructor with 'required' Autowired annotation: ...
```

Is it possible to have overloaded autowired constructors? If yes, what is the right way to do it?

Thank you!

Comment: Describe scenarios where each constructor should be called. Specify the conditions

Answer (score 3):

1. You need to define which constructor Spring will be prioritizing by writing something like this: `@Autowired(required=true)` or `@Autowired(required=false)`. You are only allowed to have one constructor with `@Autowired(required=true)`. By default, if you don't define the required property, it will be set to true, which is the problem in your case.
2. I don't see the point of having two Autowired constructors if only one of them will be wired anyway. If you're trying to Autowire the two instances of `ClassA`, it might be better to add the `@Autowired` annotation to the setters or the variables.