# Can I make Spring supply @Autowired constructors with nulls while a Bean is feature-toggled off?

Tags: spring, autowired, featuretoggle

I am developing a new feature that should be hidden behind a `FeatureToggleX`. As part of that, I need to add a new dependency `b` to my `SomeClass`:

```
class SomeClass {

  private OldDependency a;
  private NewDependency b;

  @Autowired
  public SomeClass(OldDependency a, NewDependency b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
  }

}
```

I use a custom `IfActive` annotation as `Conditional` that serves `TheToggledDependency` if, and only if, `FeatureToggleX` is active:

```
@Component
@IfActive("FeatureToggleX")
class TheToggledDependency implements NewDependency {
}
```

**How can I make Spring temporarily wire `b = null` while `FeatureToggleX` is off?**

Is there a clean way to plug a generic solution into Spring's wiring process that detects `IfActive` components and supplies `null`s in their places?

---

- As recommended in [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37893855/spring-overloaded-constructor-autowiring), I considered `@Autowired(required = false)` - maybe in combination with overloading `SomeClass`'s constructor - to allow omitting `b`, but this has the side effect that it also legalizes omitting `a`, which should be an error.
- I could provide an alternative dummy `IfInactive` variant of `NewDependency`, but that would fill my project with worthless dummies that I need to remember removing when the toggle is removed.
- Similarly, I could build two variants of `SomeClass`, one that has `NewDependency` and a second that is completely unaware of it, and choose between the two depending on the toggle. However, that is impractical for larger classes because it duplicates other, unaffected functionality.

Comment: You might want to have a look at SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnServletContext(Object target, ServletContext sc). You can autowire any dependencies in your annotation processor.

Answer (score 1):

No, at least not in the constructor. One way to deal with this kind of things is setter injection.

So you would have something like this (duck-typing here):

```
class SomeClass {


  private OldDependency a;
  private NewDependency b;

  @Autowired
  public SomeClass(OldDependency a) {
    this.a = a;
  }

  @Autorired(required=false)
  public void setNewDependency(NewDependency b) {
   this.b = b;
  }

}
```

I hope this helps.